How to stop the requests from being performed in Jetpack Compose?
I created an app for daily workouts with Jetpack Compose. What I need is to display and manage the daily workouts:
Years(
    response = { years ->
        Log.d(TAG, years.toString())

        Months(
            response = { months ->
                Log.d(TAG, years.toString())

                Days(
                    response = { days ->
                        Log.d(TAG, days.toString())

                        Workouts(
                            response = { workouts ->
                                Log.d(TAG, workouts.toString())
                            }
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    }
)

First I read all years from Firestore, when a year is selected, I get all months, when a month is selected, I get all days, and when a day is selected I get all workouts. For all these requests I have added a real-time listener. When I display the data, everything works pretty fine, however, if I delete a workout, not only the list of workouts is recomposed, but all the other composables. For example, if I delete a workout, I get all previous logs, for days, months, and years along with the workouts. How can I stop the previous logs from being displayed?
P.S. In my ViewModel I get the data like:
var yearsResponse by mutableStateOf<YearsResponse>(Loading)
    private set

private fun getYears() = viewModelScope.launch {
    repo.getYears().collect { response ->
        yearsResponse = response
    }
}

Edit:
@Composable
fun Years(
    viewModel: YearsViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    content: @Composable (years: Years) -> Unit
) {
    when(val yearsResponse = viewModel.yearsResponse) {
        is Response.Success -> content(yearsResponse.data)
        is Response.Failure -> log(yearsResponse.e)
    }
}

And here is how I delete a workout:
override suspend fun deleteWorkout(id: String): Response<Boolean> = try {
    ref.document(id).delete().await()
    Success(true)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Failure(e)
}


Please edit your post and include the Years, Months and Days Composables. Please also include the full code how you are deleting a workout.

@BenjyTec Please check the edit.
